# How does the phone scan LTE signal

Tags: android, telecommunication, lte, 4g

I have a cellphone (HTC desire 510, an android phone) that works with band 5 of LTE, However when I build my own base station with OpeanAirInterface, and send signals at a frequency of 881Mhz(downlink), the mobile phone cannot detect my signals.

I wonder if a phone will scan all the frequencies within the band 5 (which is 869~894 for downlink), or will it only scan a subset of that band.

Besides, is there a way to look into the cellphone to find what frequencies it scanned (say via a log or the like)?

Comment: What does this have to do with android or programming at all?

Comment: This is an android phone, and is remotely relevant if any one knows how Android works with detecting cellular signals

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get this information from the chipset manufacturer's log files.

Logging systems from chipset manufacturers like Qualcomm or Nvidia for example, are not publically available; you'd have to get them from the manufacturer.  Usually only customers like phone manufacturers get access.

You can't get this information programmatically over the Android APIs (which I assume is what you are asking) - it is too low level.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, all of the frequencies present in a band are scanned to find the suitable cell.

In, LTE there are reference symbols which piggy pack the information required for the UE(phone) to decode the DL channel information and select a cell.

In order to access the information regarding the frequencies it scan you have to consult the manufacturer. If it provides an interface to access those files because bands related information is logged but is only accessible by manufacturer.